# The onLoad event fires before the image has completed loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload

I am having a bit of an issue with image loading in JavaScript. I want a series of images to load sequentially i.e. image 2 only starts loading when image 1 has completely finished loading.

The problem I am finding is that the JavaScript `onLoad` method does not fire when the image has completed loading, but when the image starts loading. Therefore the smallest image is always going to be the first to load regardless of where in the queue it is. I have put together [a simple example of what i mean](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm8MR/) in JS fiddle (HTML and JS code is below as well).

Any ideas how I can wait until the image has completely loaded before starting to load the next one - it can't be that hard surely?

*Note :* I originally wrote it using the jQuery `.load` function and got the same result which is why I was messing about in raw JS.

HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="" alt="image 1" width="210" height="174"></li>
    <li><img src="" alt="image 2" width="210" height="174"></li>
    <li><img src="" alt="image 3" width="210" height="174"></li>
    <li><img src="" alt="image 4" width="210" height="174"></li>
    <li><img src="" alt="image 5" width="210" height="174"></li>
</ul>

<a href="#" id="loader">Load the images</a>
```

JS code:

```
        var imgArr = [
        "http://media.topshop.com/wcsstore/ConsumerDirectStorefrontAssetStore/images/colors/color7/cms/pages/static/static-0000038166/images/zine-HP-UK.jpg",
        "http://media.topshop.com/wcsstore/ConsumerDirectStorefrontAssetStore/images/colors/color7/cms/pages/static/static-0000038166/images/Valentine_UK.jpg",
        "http://media.topshop.com/wcsstore/ConsumerDirectStorefrontAssetStore/images/colors/color7/cms/pages/static/static-0000038166/images/crop_UK__.jpg",
        "http://media.topshop.com/wcsstore/ConsumerDirectStorefrontAssetStore/images/colors/color7/cms/pages/static/static-0000038166/images/hitlist_UK--.jpg",
        "http://media.topshop.com/wcsstore/ConsumerDirectStorefrontAssetStore/images/colors/color7/cms/pages/static/static-0000038166/images/chinese_new_year_UK_new_0402.jpg"
    ],
    totalImgs = imgArr.length,
    count = 0;

    function onLoaded(count) {
        console.log("fired onload "+count);
        var currentImg = $('li:eq('+count+') img');
        currentImg.attr('src', imgArr[count]).css('display','block');
        count++;
        if (count < totalImgs) {
            loadImg(count);
        };
    }

    function loadImg(count) {
        imgObj = new Image()
        imgObj.src = imgArr[count];
        imgObj.onLoad = onLoaded(count);                        
    }

    $('#loader').click(function() {
        loadImg(count);
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that not the handler function is assigned to the `onload` event of the `Image` but the return value of `onLoaded`. You'd need to say `imgObj.onload = onLoaded;` For the `currentImg` you can use `this` as the handler will be invoked on the `Image` object. For passing other parameters, an alternative way is needed.

Comment: Thanks Marcell i have removed the () so that onLoaded isn't called immediately, but now the onLoaded function doesn't get called at all. Am i being really stupid and missing something really fundamental here?

I have edited [the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jm8MR/1/) to reflect the change.

Comment: Hang on, it is me being an idiot!! I was calling `.onLoad` instead of `.onload`. All working now, thanks Marcell.

Answer (score 2):

Am sure you moved on from this error seeing it was asked over 2yrs ago; nonetheless I think for the benefit of others I will point out what I believe is your mistake.

You're using `imgObj.onLoad` instead of `imgObj.onload`. Javascript is case-sensitive and there is no native "onLoad" event.

The rest of the code should work well when you fix this.